# Problems with Jquery Autocomplete and Spring2.5.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring-mvc

I am trying to display autocomplete list using JQuery and Spring 2.5.6, but I am getting json to the front end, but I can't able to display it.

```
 $(function() {
    $("#globalSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/autoSearch.htm",
                data: {
                    term : request.term
                },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    // this is the alert output its displaying:{"list":["ernst","ernst&nbsp"]} 
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        //its not alerting anything here
                        alert(JSON.stringify(item, null, 4));
                        return{
                            value: item.list
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

here is my spring controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/autoSearch.htm")
public ModelAndView autoSearch(
        @RequestParam(value = "term", required = false) String term
       ) throws ParseException, IOException {

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("inventoryHandler called");
    }

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    int i = 0;
    model.put("list", getBaseModel().getSearchServiceBean().autoCompleter(term));
    return new ModelAndView("jsonView", model);
}
```

can anyone please tell me how can I display the autocomplete list.

Thanks in Advance,

Best Regards,
Raja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/autoSearch.htm")
    public ModelAndView autoSearch(
            @RequestParam(value = "term", required = false) String term
    ) throws ParseException, IOException {

```
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("inventoryHandler called");
    }

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("list", getBaseModel().getSearchServiceBean().searchAutoComplete(term));
    return new ModelAndView("jsonView", model);
}
```

and in views.properties file view should be set like

jsonView.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView

and in javascript the autocomplete will work by using the following code:

```
        $("#searchEmail").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                ajaxCall(request, response);
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("#searchEmail").val(ui.item.value);
                $("#emailSearch-form").submit();
            }
        });

        function ajaxCall(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/autoSearch.htm",
                data: {
                    term : request.term
                },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.list, function(item) {
                        return{
                            label: item,
                            value: item
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In spring 3.x onwards you would use the @ResponseBody annotation, for example:

```
public @ResponseBody List<String> autocomplete(@RequestParam(value = "term", required = false) String term) {
    //Go get your results for the autocomplete term
    List<String> termResults = ...;

    return termResults;
}
```

It looks to me like your response is being sent back to the client with the wrong content type and is being interpreted as text/html rather than JSON. You could set the response content type and write a JSON string from within your controller?

```
String json = "{\"list\":[\"ernst\",\"ernst&nbsp\"]}";
response.setContentType("application/json");
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
response.setContentLength(json.length());
writer.write(json);
```

Comment: actually I am getting json at the front end..just dont know how to return it..but finally found the solution and it is displayed below.

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the solution which is displayed below.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#globalSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/autoSearch.htm",
                data: {
                    globalSearch : request.term
                },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.list, function(value) {
                        return{
                            label: value,
                            value: value
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and in input field both name and id have to be same like

```
 <input type="text" name="globalSearch" id="globalSearch"/>
```